# How many non prime factors are in the number $N=2^5 \cdot 3^7 \cdot 9^2 \cdot 11^4 \cdot 13^3$.

Tags: combinatorics

to find non prime factors in the number
$N=2^5 \cdot 3^7 \cdot 9^2 \cdot 11^4 \cdot 13^3$.

First I tried finding all the factors by adding 1 to each of the exponents and then multiplying them
and then finding the prime factors of the given number
and then subtracting the prime factors from the total factors 
but I'm not getting the answer.

Answer is $1436$.

Comment: make sure you rewrite 9 as 3^2

Answer (score 9):

Write it as $2^5 * 3^{11} * 11^4 * 13^3$. Thus, as you said, adding one to each exponent and multiplying, we get the total number of divisors, which is $6* 12 * 5* 4 = 1440$. Subtracting the four prime factors ($2,3,11,13$) leaves us with 1436.

Answer (score 1):

Consider 1 as a default prime factor of any number in this type of problem as well. Then the number of non prime factors is the number of factors minus the number of prime factors, or $1440-5=1435$.

Comment: $1$ is not considered a prime number.

Comment: $9$ is not a prime factor and $3$ is already represented.